# Вставить класс из другого файла

Tags: java

Есть 2 java файла. В первом имеется публичный класс  Selected. Как вставить его во второй java файл? Что то типа include как в PHP

Comment: `import` не работает чтоли?

Comment: А как вы пробуете то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самой первой строчкой в первом классе (.java файле, в котором прописан публичный класс) должен быть указан пакет.
Например, если в первом классе у тебя написано

```
package com.stackoverflow.yok;
```

То во втором классе после оператора `package` ты пишешь

```
import com.stackoverflow.yok.Selected;
```

или

```
import com.stackoverflow.yok.*;
```

Так же можно просто 2 класса приписать к одному пакету, тогда импортировать не надо.

Comment: мне казалось, что импорт пакета целиком должен выглядеть как `import com.stackoverflow.yok.*;`. Разве можно написать как у вас?

Comment: Я собственно к чему? Получается, если написать, как у вас в ответе, будет ошибка. Вы бы поправили и дополнили ответ импортом конкретного класса

Comment: Поправил ``````